# python - Error a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, int

I have read many answers and documentation but I cannot understand the problem.

In this code I did not put the real HexRegHash becouse I think it is seecret.
This is my code

```
HexRegHash= '0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF0000000000000F3200ACDF'
RegHash = binascii.unhexlify(HexRegHash)
UsernameOffset = int(binascii.hexlify(RegHash[0xc]), 16) + 0xcc
Username = RegHash[UsernameOffset:UsernameOffset+UsernameLength].replace('\x00','')
print('Username (offset 0xc): ' + Username + "\n")
```

This is my error.

```
  File "hash2.py", line 94, in <module>
    UsernameOffset = int(binascii.hexlify(RegHash[0xc]), 16) + 0xcc
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

Comment: you didn't mention what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Now do you understand what I want? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is just telling you that `binascii.hexlify(input)` wants binary data as an input. `regHash[0xc]` just returns an int, not binary data.

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html):

> binascii.**hexlify**(data)
>
> Return the hexadecimal representation of the binary data. Every byte of data is converted into the corresponding 2-digit hex representation. The returned bytes object is therefore twice as long as the length of data.

A correct input would e.g. be regHash itself, or any other binary data.
For any other help you might need to explain what the code is supposed to do and why.